# Swift -Ounchecked and Assertions

Tags: ios, swift, assert

## Preface

In Swift, `ENABLE_NS_ASSERTIONS` is ignored, and whether assertions are on or off is dependent of `SWIFT_OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL`, [see here for more information](http://blog.krzyzanowskim.com/2015/03/09/swift-asserts-the-missing-manual/).

- `assert()` is active for `-Onone`
- `assertionFailure()` is active for
  `-Onone`
- `precondition()` is active for `-Onone` and `-O`
- `preconditionFailure()` is active for `-Onone`, `-O` and `-Ounchecked`
- `fatalError()` is active for `-Onone`, `-O` and `-Ounchecked`

## What I want to achieve

Debug and Beta Builds should have assertions **enabled**, Release Builds should have assertions **disabled**.

## How I could do it

I could write all my assertions in Swift via the `precondition` method and compile Release builds with the `-Ounchecked` flag, beta builds with the `-O` flag.

## What I'm unsure about

The default in iOS for Release builds is `-O`. Is there anything advised against using `-Ounchecked` for release builds? Which other unwanted side effects could this cause?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should definitely **not** compile `-Ounchecked` for release in order to use `precondition` only while testing.  Compiling `-Ounchecked` also disables checks for things like array out of bounds and unwrapping `nil`, that could lead to some pretty nasty production bugs involving memory corruption.

You can control assertion behaviour independently of compiler optimization settings via the `-assert-config` argument to `swiftc`:

```
$ cat assert.swift 
assert(false, "assertion asserted")
println("made it here...")
$ swiftc -Onone assert.swift; ./assert
assertion failed: assertion asserted: file assert.swift, line 1
Illegal instruction: 4
$ swiftc -O assert.swift; ./assert
made it here...
$ swiftc -O -assert-config Debug assert.swift; ./assert
assertion failed: assertion asserted: file assert.swift, line 1
Illegal instruction: 4
$
```

It doesn’t look like there’s an Xcode Build Settings toggle for this, but you can add using the “Other Swift Flags” setting.

Comment: touché on that one :-)