# Which optimization level should I choose for release?

Tags: swift, xcode, debugging, optimization, build

I've read about swift assertions from [here](https://andybargh.com/swift-assertions/) and trying to find out more about optimizations.

for `debug` (default):

> compiler performs no optimizations which in turn makes debugging your
>   code and tracing it back to the original line of source code
>   significantly easier.

for `-O`:

> the compiler will strip symbols from your code (such as variable and
>   function names) and perform optimization on your code to improve its
>   performance

for `-Ounchecked`:

> This is the optimization level you want if you’re going for the
>   absolute best blazing performance you can. Although this level of
>   optimization does improve performance, it only achieves this through
>   the introduction of a certain level of risk. At this optimization
>   level, the Swift compiler will skip many of the safety checks it would
>   normally perform within the code in order to squeeze out the last
>   ounce of performance

**My questions are:**

- To make things faster for users...when I archive and release my app, do I need to go in a tweak anything? Or archives are defaulted to `-O`?
- Which is the version that I should give for my users? `-O` or `-Ounchecked`?

Comment: You set the optimization settings in your Project Settings under Build Settings -> Optimization Level.  I assume the optimization level you want depends vastly on the application you are writing (this is too broad).  I see no real reason to stray from the default.

Comment: @JAL you mean when I archive...the optimization level doesn't change? So basically if I don't care at all about debugging...then perhaps setting to `Ounchecked` is the right choice?

Comment: The optimization settings of the archive will be whatever you have set for the scheme that is used during the archive.  I don't see why you should use `-Ounchecked` unless you have a really good reason to (are you using OpenGL?  Metal?).

Comment: [Compiling -Ounchecked also disables checks for things like array out of bounds and unwrapping nil, that could lead to some pretty nasty production bugs involving memory corruption.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30098021/2415822)

Comment: @JAL Thanks. so you answered my first question. for my 2nd question: OK, never use `-Ounchecked` as I have no use for OpenGL/Metal, should I use `-O`? Confused as to where that should be used? Or I guess I can consider it something unneeded for a regular app (tabeView, network calls, SSO, login) Do you mind putting that in answer so I can accept it?

Comment: It's also generally good to use `-wmo` (whole module optimisation) alongside `-O` (although I believe this is now the default for a release build in the latest version of Xcode).

Comment: @Hamish correct me if I'm wrong: so you're saying the *opposite* of what JAL is saying. That is Xcode will default your releases to `-O`. JAL said it would be "whatever you have set for the scheme"

Comment: @Honey Hamish is correct, every scheme/target has a default optimization value, which is set to `-Onone` for Debug and `-O -whole-module-optimization` for Release by default.  Create a new iOS Xcode project and look in the settings.  What I'm saying is that an archive will take whatever you have set for that scheme.

Comment: I'm hesitant to provide an actual answer because the question "Which is the version that I should give for my users? `-O` or `-Ounchecked`?" is too broad, and depends vastly on the application context.

Comment: @JAL It's obvious that it depends. I don't know what it *depends* on and how to make that decision. Though the OpenGL/Metal was a good touchstone. :D