# What is the difference between User Defined SWIFT_WHOLE_MODULE_OPTIMIZATION and Swift Optimization Level?

Tags: swift, optimization, compilation

I'm currently looking into optimizing my project's compile time.

Although I've known there's something called **whole module optimization** (**WMO** for short), but am afraid of checking it out in **Build Settings** since I didn't really dig deep into it yet.

As I understand it:

**WMO** should result in a faster code execution but slightly increase the compile time, because it compiles whole module files as one whole instead of compiling each file separately in parallel, according to this [Swift official blog on whole module optimizations](https://swift.org/blog/whole-module-optimizations/)  .

So it's recommended to set Swift optimization level as follows:

- For **Debug** configuration, set to `None [-Onone]`
- For **Release** configuration, set to `Fast, Whole Module Optimization [-O -whole-module-optimization]` as it is not that important to have best compile time for occasional release builds.

However, when digging for tips about how to reduce compile time for **Debug** configuration, I found this **User Defined** settings:

- `SWIFT_WHOLE_MODULE_OPTIMIZATION = YES` for **Debug**
- `SWIFT_WHOLE_MODULE_OPTIMIZATION = NO` for **Release**

This settings reduced my **Debug** compile time almost *by half*.

Since I'm new to Swift compiler and **User Defined** settings, I tried to find official documentation on `SWIFT_WHOLE_MODULE_OPTIMIZATION` but what's confusing is there's not any documentation there online.

People just say it reduces compile time but no further explanation, or they conflicts with Swift Optimization Level mentioned above.

As I understand it, this settings set to `YES` should increase the compile time as it enables **WMO**. Therefore I think I took **WMO** wrong.

**Questions:**

1. What is the difference between `Swift Optimization Level` settings and `SWIFT_WHOLE_MODULE_OPTIMIZATION`?
2. Why does `SWIFT_WHOLE_MODULE_OPTIMIZATION` reduces compile time?

Thank you!

Comment: This [thread](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/103159) might be useful. I personally dont like to add custom stuff on this settings. I just made changes on `compilation mode` and `optimization level` (Xcode 10.1)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. The main difference is that `whole-module-optimization` refers to how the compiler optimises *modules* and the `Swift Optimization Level` refers to each file compilation. You can read more about the different flags for `Swift Optimization Level` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44313032/which-optimization-level-should-i-choose-for-release).
2. `SWIFT_WHOLE_MODULE_OPTIMIZATION` improves compilation time because the compiler has a more global view on all functions, methods and relations between files, allowing it to ignore unused functions, optimise compile order, among other improvements. It also focuses on compiling only modified files, which means that even with that flag activated, if you clean your project and delete the derived data folder, you will still have a bigger compilation time during the first run.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I'm not sure if I get it, so please bear with me. As I understand your answer: 

In general wmo decreases the compile time, but: 

-  When enabling it for every file with `Swift Optimization Level` it compiles every single file with every build and therefore it's considered to be bad option for development, but it's okay for release. 

-  When enabling it with `SWIFT_WHOLE_MODULE_OPTIMIZATION` and disabling it for each file it only compiles changed files and therefore it's faster. 

Is this correct?

Comment: `-wmo` is a *module* option, it means that when you enable it, gives the compiler a global vision over all files and compiles the whole project as one. This reduces time because the compiler knows what changed on each file and how that could affect other files and optimises decisions to compile everything it needs to. The *Swift Optimization Level* is a flag that states how each file will be handled, independently of the `-wmo` option being enabled or not. **TL;DR**, yes, you are correct